# Handling Runtime exception in Java

Tags: java, exception

I have the following piece of code

```
 try{//do something
     }
  catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e, e);
        if (e instanceof RuntimeException) {
            throw (RuntimeException) e;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

the findbugs stataic analysis tool throws this warning on it

> instanceof will always return true for all nonnull values in methodX, since all RuntimeException are instances of RuntimeException

what i dont understand is that its Exception which is being caught and not the RuntimeException, so why this warning ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also try following code. This will be better to read and maintain.

```
try{//do something
}
catch (RuntimeException e) {
    throw e;
} 
catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps, the `// do something` code does not throw any checked exception, so the only exceptions you can get in your try-block are unchecked ones (subclassing `RuntimeException`).

Answer (score 2):

Probably there is no methods that throws not RuntimeException in "try" part. Therefore, you can use construction

```
catch(RuntimeException e)
{
 //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Throwables.html#propagate%28java.lang.Throwable%29. It does exactly what you want. Today I did the replacement for the same reason (findbugs warning), also looked the source of this method.