# Java 8 lambda catching exception

Tags: java-8, unchecked-exception

From the book *Java 8 for the impatient* by Cay Horstmann:

> Didn’t you always hate it that you had to deal with checked
>   exceptions in a Runnable? Write a method `uncheck` that catches all
>   checked exceptions and turns them into unchecked exceptions. For
>   example,
>
> ```
> new Thread(uncheck(
> () -> { System.out.println("Zzz"); Thread.sleep(1000); })).start();
> // Look, no catch (InterruptedException)!
> ```
>
> Hint: Define an interface `RunnableEx` whose `run` method may throw any
>   exceptions. Then implement
>
> ```
> public static Runnable uncheck(RunnableEx runner)
> ```
>
> Use a lambda expression inside the uncheck function.

For which I code like this:

```
public interface RunnableEx {
    void run() throws Exception;
}

public class TestUncheck {
    public static Runnable uncheck(RunnableEx r) {
        return new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    r.run();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(uncheck(
                () -> {
                    System.out.println("Zzz");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
        )).start();
    }
}
```

Did I do according to what was hinted? Is there a better way of doing this?

Also there is another complementary question:

> Why can’t you just use `Callable<Void>` instead of `RunnableEx?`

Answer (score 4):

Your code fails to wrap the checked exception into an unchecked one. Further, it doesn’t following the hint to use a lambda expression. A corrected version would be:

```
public static Runnable uncheck(RunnableEx r) {
    return () -> {
        try {
            r.run();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    };
}
```

There are indeed possibilities to improve this further. Since the whole purpose of the `RunnableEx` interface is to wrap a `Runnable`, you could place the factory method inside the interface itself:

```
public interface RunnableEx {
    void run() throws Exception;
    public static Runnable uncheck(RunnableEx r) {
        return () -> {
            try {
                r.run();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Of course, now your calling code has to be adapted to:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Thread(RunnableEx.uncheck(
            () -> {
                System.out.println("Zzz");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
    )).start();
}
```

Now, the interface itself could implement the wrapping feature, becoming compatible with `Runnable`, which would eliminate the need to have a `Runnable` and a `RunnableEx` instance to represent a single action:

```
public interface RunnableEx extends Runnable {
    void runWithException() throws Exception;
    @Override default void run() {
            try {
                runWithException();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
    }
    public static Runnable uncheck(RunnableEx r) {
        return r;
    }
}
```

Note that while the calling code doesn’t change syntactically, it will implicitly create a `Runnable` instance in the first place, when creating the `RunnableEx` instance, that’s why `uncheck` becomes a no-op, merely serving as a marker that a `RunnableEx` should be created rather than a `Runnable`. With this interface definition, you could achieve the same via

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Thread( (RunnableEx) () -> {
            System.out.println("Zzz");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    ).start();
}
```

---

The reason why you can’t “just use” a `Callable<Void>` here, is that `Callable<Void>` still is a `Callable`, requiring the implementation code to return a value. In other words, there is no implicit conversion from `void` to `Void`. So you can use it, but the lambda expression would require a `return null;` statement at its end then (`null` is the only value compatible with `Void`).

```
public class TestUncheck {
    public static Runnable uncheck(Callable<Void> r) {
        return () -> {
            try { r.call(); }
            catch (Exception e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(uncheck(
                () -> {
                    System.out.println("Zzz");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    return null;
                }
        )).start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This way of catching exceptions from lambdas works fine, and is (with a few additions) the one implemented in the `Unchecked` class from [jOOλ](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL), a popular Java library.

For comparison, see their static method [`Unchecked.runnable`](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jooq/lambda/Unchecked.java#L90), which is identical to your solution, with the exception of their `Exception` handler and to the lambda abreviating the return value.

With regards to the assignment from *Java 8 to the Impatients*, your `uncheck` method does not use a lambda (for this, see the `Unchecked.runnable` method), and does not throw an unchecked exception. For this, your `catch`block (currently empty) needs to wrap the exception into an unchecked exception. There are many ways to do it, and many questions on SO are relevant:

1. [How to wrap checked exceptions but keep the original runtime exceptions in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39719370/how-to-wrap-checked-exceptions-but-keep-the-original-runtime-exceptions-in-java)
2. [Replace a checked exception with a runtime exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944216/replace-a-checked-exception-with-a-runtime-exception)
3. [Handling Runtime exception in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717585/handling-runtime-exception-in-java)

But a simple way is:

```
throw (e instanceof RuntimeException) ? (RuntimeException) e : new RuntimeException(e);
```

Finally, to answer the `Callable<Void>`question, I am assuming you mean "instead of `Runnable`"? If so, it is because the constructors from [`Thread`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) take a `Runnable`as an argument.